# When do we need the instance variable and when do we need string name for a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading Agile Rails Web Dev book and so far for partials I had learned than we can call their name in a string form or if there is a collection of objects we can pass the object name and rails will figure out that it needs to loop through it as a collection.
Now I saw this code and suddenly all I had learned got confused:

[image]

```
<%= render @cart %>
```

My question is what is it `@cart`,  Why it is not `'cart'` ? And how should I have known that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, so I'm just commenting, but I think rails knows to look for a partial named _cart based on the type of @cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) suggests that when you do "render @cart", Rails introspects the model name of @cart and looks for a partial by that name in the current view path.

The implementation of render :partial actually calls to_partial_path on the passed object. A User object would by default return 'users/user'. So I'd check to see if the Cart class implements to_partial_path to return 'layouts/cart'.

Comment: "In the current view path" ?  But they have written this code in the application layout one.  Yes we also have a _cart_html.erb in the cart view folder

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong but I believe that behind the scenes Rails will render a partial for anything that has a `to_partial_path` method. In this case I'm assuming `@cart` is an ActiveRecord object and all ActiveRecord objects respond to [`to_partial_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_partial_path).

Try adding this to your template and see what it outputs. It should be the path of your partial.

```
<%= @cart.to_partial_path %>
```